# what will be definition of function "X509_dup" in openssl library?

Tags: ssl, openssl, cryptography

can someone please point me to X509_dup function definition? and how we can reach to function definition to x509_dup if we have openssl library with us?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean where is it defined in the documentation or where is it defined in the source code?

If you are after the documentation then see the man page here:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/X509_dup.html

Including the header file "openssl/x509.h" will get you access to the function.

Or, perhaps you mean where is it defined in the source code. If so then it is defined by a macro here (for OpenSSL 1.1.0):

https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_0-stable/crypto/x509/x_x509.c#L86

Or here (for OpenSSL 1.0.2):

https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_2-stable/crypto/asn1/x_x509.c#L143